# Java 8: Introduce streams and lambdas to method

Tags: java, lambda, java-8, java-stream

I have been working on this `Java` method that calculates the price of an item based on certain criteria.

I managed to write it in a classic, iterative manner, but I would like to

re-write it (or parts of it), using streams and lambdas.

Any advice or guidance towards the right direction would be much

appreciated.

Thank you.

This is my method:

```
private void quantityBasedDiscount(Kart kart) {

    BigDecimal totalDiscount = BigDecimal.ZERO;
    BigDecimal cnt = new BigDecimal(0);
    List<Long> idsChekcked = new ArrayList<>();
    var items = kart.getItems();
    final var size = items.size();
    for (int i = 0; i < size; i++) {
        if (idsChekcked.contains(items.get(i).getId()) ||
            items.get(i).getQuantityDiscountThreshold().compareTo(BigDecimal.ZERO) == 0) {
            continue;
        }
        cnt = cnt.add(BigDecimal.valueOf(1));

        for (int j = i + 1; j < size; j++) {
            if (items.get(j).getId() == items.get(i).getId()) {
                cnt = cnt.add(BigDecimal.valueOf(1));
            }
        }
        final var quantityDiscountThreshold = items.get(i).getQuantityDiscountThreshold();
        if (cnt.compareTo(quantityDiscountThreshold) >= 0) {
            cart.setMessage("Discount is applied");
            for (int k = 0; k < size; k++) {
                if (items.get(k).getId() == items.get(i).getId()) {
                    final var item = items.get(k);
                    item.setDiscount(item.getPrice().subtract(item.getQuantityDiscountValue()));
                    final BigDecimal discount = item.getDiscount();
                    cart.getItems().get(k).setDiscount(discount);
                    totalDiscount = totalDiscount.add(discount);
                }
            }
            idsChekcked.add(items.get(i).getId());
        }

    }
    kart.setTotal(cart.getTotal().subtract(totalDiscount));
    kart.setTotalDiscount(totalDiscount);
}
```

Comment: "but I would like to re-write it (or parts of it), using streams and lambdas" why? What do you think the advantage would be?

Comment: Does your code work? Do you know what your code does? What benefit are you hoping to get, when rewriting it with lambdas / streams?

Comment: It is too complex code to convert it to use streams, even if you do that, code will be not readable i think, better to keep it as is

Comment: I simply want to make the connection between iterative and declarative style, by looking at two implementations of the same code. I understand when I read about Java 8 features in tutorials, but I struggle to make the jump from taking something that Ive written and re-writing it in Java 8. The code as it is now, works fine

Answer (score 1):

You can refactor some parts of this using stream.

(As advice, you should start by refactoring this function into small steps, even if they are not using stream.)

Keep in mind to create tiny functions with meaningful names.

You can have something like using stream

```
kart.getItems().stream()
    .filter(it -> containsId(it))
    .map(it -> legacyMethodHere(it))
    .collect(Collectors.toList());
```

you can also use `peek()` and pass it a `Consumer` which is a function that returns void. Useful if you do side effects like adding smth to `cnt`.

As stream is more "functional", you should use it as a flow of functions, those functions should not have side effect and be predictable.